# Milk storage freeze or refrigerator?

Tags: terminology, slang

I was in some american company and during preparing a coffee I asked some girl with asian face "where is refrigerator?" She got confused and asked me "what do you mean???". I asked with details "where is a milk?", she answered "oh, in freeze".

So my question is if milk is stored in refrigerator why people use *freeze* word or she is mistaken?

Can somebody spread the light on this problem?

Comment: I have never, to my recollection, heard "freeze" used to refer to a freezer (or refrigerator) in the US.  It is possible that she said "fridge" and you misunderstood.

Answer (score 1):

Here in the United States, people call the place where you store milk **the refrigerator** or just **the fridge**. Ice cream is stored in **the freezer**, which is much colder than the fridge. (You would not want to store milk in the freezer, because it would freeze solid!) This seems to be quite standard terminology. Perhaps the girl was not a native English speaker and was not familiar with the proper words for "refrigerator" and "freezer"; or (more likely) she said "fridge" but you heard "freeze."

Comment: [RHK Webster's](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/freezer) shows that the two words are synonymous, and Collins that they were once more synonymous. The 'below freezing' constraint does apply, meaning that only devices (even if efficient fridges rather than true 'freezers') held below this temperature should be called 'freezers'.

Comment: looks like not native ( as I remember), makes sense, thanks

Comment: @EdwinAshworth RHK Webster's defines "freezer" as "a refrigerator, refrigerator compartment, cabinet, or room **held at or below 32°F (0°C)**", so it's not a direct synonym. I've never in my entire life heard a freezer called "a refrigerator" in common usage. I do believe that they were once synonymous, though, since until recent times it was usually just known as "the icebox" :)

Comment: @Nick Weinberg A 'synonym' is defined as 'a word which may be substituted for another **in some usage/s** with no/very little effect on overall meaning.' Hence the possibility of being 'more synonymous' (being more widely interchangeable and/or being even closer in meaning where interchangeable)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thank you for the information, and for the edit to your original comment. Now that you've edited the comment to indicate that the temperature difference is important to distinguishing between the two words, I agree with you.

Comment: What are 'chiller cabinets'  (typically holding dairy products in supermarkets, at say 5 degrees C) called in the States?

Comment: Good question! I've heard them informally called "coolers" ("I have to grab a gallon of 1% from the milk cooler") though it seems like there must be a better word for them. The section of the store that has the coolers is called the "refrigerated section."

Comment: @Rathony Thank you for your perspective. I provided the speculation as a possible explanation for the misunderstanding; I hope that by saying "perhaps" I made it clear that I was only speculating. I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "There is nothing confusing for any non-native English speaker who lives in the US and employed by a company."

Comment: @Rathony Ok, now I think I understand -- it's likely that the woman said "fridge" and the OP heard "freeze."

Comment: For the sake of completeness, here in the United Kingdom, people also call the place where you store milk the **refrigerator** or **fridge**, and it will have a *minimum* temperature of >0°C. Ice cream is stored in the **freezer**, with a *maximum* temperature of <0°C. A **refrigerator** may contain a small **freezer** compartment, with its own internal door.

Comment: @TrevorD - That's pretty much identical to US usage.

Comment: @NickWeinberg "it's likely that the woman said "fridge" and the OP heard "freeze" yes, she has strange accent Chinese or Japanese so maybe she called it fridge but there is only difference in end word sound `[friːz]` and `[ frɪdʒ ]`. Thanks